# Debug init on Qemu using gdb

Tags: linux, gdb, init, qemu

i am trying to emulate cavium octeon's mips64 linux kernel on Qemu.I am currently having some issues with use mode init code and want to debug init.i am starting the Qemu using -s -S option in the command line and running the gdb using command

**ddd --debugger /OCTEON-SDK/tools/bin/mips64-octeon-linux-gnu-gdb /OCTEON-SDK/linux/kernel_2.6/linux/vmlinux**

and then attaching the gdb with command

**target remote localhost:1234**

The gdb is currently showing only the instructions running in kernel space.

What i want to ask is there any method by which i can debug the usermode init and libraries instructions step by step as in case of kernel space?
For example if **printf** is issued from init then i want to see that which instructions are being executed in the libraries and how the control is returned to kernel ?

Comment: It will depend if the gdb support for MIPS can handle the transition between kernel and user space. Try putting a break-point on resume_userspace in the kernel and single step from there and see if the transition is handled.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to step debug BusyBox's `/sbin/init` using the procedure described at: [Is it possible to use gdb and qemu to debug linux user space programs and kernel space simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271901/is-it-possible-to-use-gdb-and-qemu-to-debug-linux-user-space-programs-and-kernel/46636070#46636070)

The only additional things you have to keep in mind are:

- `/sbin/init` is just a symlink to `busybox`, so you must use `/bin/busybox` as the object file
- the "main" function for `/sbin/init` is actually `init_main`, following BusyBox' convention of calling the main for each pseudo-executable as `<exec>_main`

It is a bit flaky, but mostly just works.