# Is it possible to use gdb and qemu to debug linux user space programs and kernel space simultaneously?

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, gdb, qemu

So far, with gdb + qemu, I can step into/over linux kernel source code. Is it possible to debug the user space programs simultaneously? For example, single step a program from user space to kernel space so I can observe the changes of registers on the qemu monitor by issuing `info registers`?

Comment: Why not? To see a task switch, try stepping through [`__schedule`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/core.c?v=3.17#L2753), specifically right as it "returns" to the new task.  Otherwise, try setting breakpoints on various system calls to see what happens when a process calls them.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon, but can I break when the program is still running in userspace ? Actually I am more interested in observe the registers when the process is running in user space.

Comment: @JeffLi did you managed to debug a user space program in qemu? I'm trying to do the same but can not figure out how

Answer (score 6):

**Minimal step-by-setep setup**

[Mahouk is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28831058/895245), but here is a [fully automated QEMU + Buildroot example](https://cirosantilli.com/linux-kernel-module-cheat/gdb-step-debug-userland-processes) which presuposes that you [already know how to debug the kernel with QEMU + gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408041/how-to-debug-the-linux-kernel-with-gdb-and-qemu/33203642#33203642) and a more detailed exaplanation:

```
readelf -h myexecutable | grep Entry
```

Gives:

```
  Entry point address:               0x4003a0
```

So inside GDB we need to do:

```
add-symbol-file myexecutable 0x4003a0
b main
```

And only then start the executable in QEMU:

```
myexecutable
```

A more reliable way to do that is to set `myexecutable` as the `init` process if you can do that.

`add-symbol-file` is also mentioned at: [How to load multiple symbol files in gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380204/how-to-load-multiple-symbol-files-in-gdb)

**Why would you ever want to do this instead of `gdbserver`?**

I can only see one use case for this so far: debugging `init`: [Debug init on Qemu using gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273614/debug-init-on-qemu-using-gdb)

Otherwise, why not just use the following more reliable method, e.g. to step into a syscall:

- start two remote GDBs:

  - one with `qemu-system-* -s`
  - the other `gdbserver myexecutable` as explained at: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/cross-debugging-for-mips-elf-with-qemu-toolchain/16214#16214
- step in `gdbserver`'s GDB as close as possible to the system call, which often mean stepping into the libc
- on the QEMU's GDB, do e.g. `b sys_read` for the read syscall
- back on `gdbserver`, do `continue`

I propose this because:

- using the QEMU GDB for userland can lead to random jumps as the kernel context switches to another process that uses the same virtual addresses
- I was not able to load shared libraries properly without `gdbserver`: attempting `sharedlibrary` directly gives:

  ```
  (gdb) sharedlibrary ../../staging/lib/libc.so.0
  No loaded shared libraries match the pattern `../../staging/lib/libc.so.0'.
  ```

  As a consequence, since most kernel interactions go through the stdib, you would need to do a lot of smart assembly stepping to find the kernel entry, which could be impractical.

  Until, that is, someone writes a smarter GDB scripts that steps every instruction until a context switch happens or until source become available. I wonder if such scripts would't be too slow, as the naive approach has the overhead of communication to-from GDB for every instruction.

  This might get you started: [Tell gdb to skip standard files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676241/tell-gdb-to-skip-standard-files/46662248#46662248)

**Parsing Linux kernel data structures**

To do userland process debug properly, that's what we would have to do eventually: [thread-aware gdb for the Linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561546/thread-aware-gdb-for-the-linux-kernel)

Answer (score 3):

I achieve it by using the gdb command add-symbol-file to add userspace programs debugging information. But you must know these programs loading addresses. so to be precise, you have to launch the kernel debugging by connecting gdb to gdbserver as usual; and then, you can add those program debugging information. You can also use .gdbinit script though. Read [this](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html)

Comment: how you identify programs loading addresses?

Comment: objdump -h <program linked file>

Comment: You look for the VMA (link address) and LMA (load address) of the .text section. These addresses give you the information you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

In mit xv6 os lab, we can use `file` command to switch symbol table between different executable including xv6 kernel or program running in user mode.

So I check whether it works or not on Linux kernel and its user programs. The result is that it also works, but we need to guarantee kernel and user programs are **statically linked**.

In summary, you can use the following steps to debug user programs:

1. When gdb and QEMU are connected, it is common that you have load `vmlinux`   symbol table. Press **ctrl+c** to stop QEMU, the gdb is waiting for following command.
2. Use `file [your user programs]` command to switch symbol table.
3. Try  set a breakpoint on your user programs , `continue` the gdb and running your user programs on QEMU.

Make sure that all programs are compiled with `-g` to build debug info and be statically linked.